# Reduce file size of pptx files using PHP

Tags: php, powerpoint, filesize, phppresentation

I am generating `PPTX` file using [this](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation) plugin. Each ppt have near about 20 or more images with approx 600-1000 kb of sizes. I am reducing images via `PHP` and then add them to PPTX.

However I am getting PPTX file size `16/17 MB` same as of image total. Is there any way to reduce file size?

I am redusing size using https://www.wecompress.com/ and I get file with 2/3 MB.

Is there any way in PHP to do so?

Comment: Is the wecompress site reducing the quality of the images by changing the format or resolution?  If yes, do that with your PHP code.

Comment: @DaveS I dont think image size reduced that much. As quality was same.

Comment: What file format are you saving the images in after reducing them via PHP and before adding them to your PPTX?   Have you looked inside the PPTX (which is actually a ZIP file) to examine the images within?

Comment: ^ and do the same with the wecompress version.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wecompress.com runs on the NXPowerLite file optimization engine (the newest version of), you can see what it's doing in detail here: https://www.neuxpower.com/office-compression/

There's quite a bit going on in there but the biggest gains come from resizing and compression.